# Accessing the local variable of other class from one class

Tags: java, user-interface, jtabbedpane

1st Class :

```
jb4=new JButton("Select the File");
jb4.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    final JFrame JF=new JFrame("Video Player");
    JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
    fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    try {
       mediaURL = fc.getSelectedFile().toURI();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    final  MediaPlayer mp= new MediaPlayer(mediaURL) ;
    panel4.add(mp);
    }
    });
tabbedPane.addTab("Video Player", createImageIcon("images/VideoPlayer.png"), panel4,"This tab is for Video Player");
panel4.add(jb4);
jb=new JButton("Close Video Frame");
jb.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                       
            // WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE???                    
    }
});
panel4.add(jb);
```

2nd Class :

```
public class MediaPlayer extends JPanel { 
 JPanel JP=new JPanel();
 JButton jb=new JButton("Close");
public MediaPlayer(URL mediauUrl)  {
    
      try{
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel());
      }catch (Exception e)
    {         e.printStackTrace();      }
  
setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
 
try { 
final Player mediaPlayer=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(new MediaLocator(mediauUrl));  // LINE A
   Component video=mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
   Component control=mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();
   
   if (video!=null) {
      add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);           
  }
    add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);           
    mediaPlayer.start();
       
     } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
   }   
}
}
```

In plain simple words :

1. I was building a Video Player using JMF.
2. In 1st Class we can see a button "jb4". On clicking this it will create
   an object of 2nd class[MediaPlayer Class] and the Video Player
   starts.
3. Now on clicking the other Button "jb" the video player should stop and
   close itself.For stopping and Closing Video I needed to
   access the Player Object(mediaPlayer) - SEE LINE A in 2nd class.
4. So my problem was that I declared that object locally inside 2nd
   Class.
5. I thought there might be some way to access that
   mediaPlayer variable of 2nd class through 1st class. I mean I
   thought I could write some code in ActionListner of Button "jb"
   which will access that mediaPlayer variable. **THIS THINKING WAS
   WRONG**.
6. **My problem was resolved when I declared Player Object
   outside the constructor which is seen in my Answer below.**

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: . What should I write in ActionPerformed function of Button jb so that it should close the video frame and just return back to normal as before.

Comment: What's stopping you from making the variable `final  MediaPlayer mp= new MediaPlayer(mediaURL);` a class member instead of a local variable?

Comment: I have edited the question. Now you all understand it easily what was the problem and how it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue myself. Thanx to [c.s.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581401/c-s) !!
The problem was that I created the Player Object Locally.
 Once I created Player object outside the MedialPlayer() constructor I was able to access it through MediaPlayer class object.
Code of Media Player Class:

```
import de.javasoft.plaf.synthetica.SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.MediaLocator;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class MediaPlayer extends javax.swing.JPanel{


// THIS IS THE SIMPLE CHANGE CHANGE THAT RESOLVED ALL THE PROBLEMS
```

//  I declared Player object outside the class and it resolved all my problems
         Player mediaPlayer;

```
public MediaPlayer(URL mediaUrl) throws Exception{    

      try{
       UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new SyntheticaAluOxideLookAndFeel());
  }catch (ParseException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {    
          e.printStackTrace();      
  }

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

try {  
   mediaPlayer=Manager.createRealizedPlayer(new MediaLocator(mediaUrl));
   Component video=mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
   Component control=mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

   if (video!=null) {
           add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);          // place the video component in the panel
              }
    add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);            // place the control in  panel

 //mediaPlayer.start();
 Thread.sleep(1000);

     } catch (IOException | NoPlayerException | CannotRealizeException | NullPointerException  e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

}
}
```